# Reformatting dataframe column issue

Tags: pandas

Why the following line of code

```
df['Startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Startdate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

won't change the following dataframe `df` with type `datetime64[ns]`  from:

```
      Startdate
0    2020-10-05
1    2002-04-18
2    2002-07-22
3    1980-02-25
4    2015-01-05
5    2014-08-14
6    2015-09-14
7    2019-05-01
8    2018-08-28
9    2004-09-01
10   2007-04-02
11   1995-04-01
12   2019-01-10
```

to:

```
     Startdate
0   05/10/2020
1   18/04/2002
2   22/07/2002
3   25/02/1980
4   05/01/2015
5   14/08/2014
6   14/09/2015
7   01/05/2019
8   28/08/2018
9   01/09/2004
10  02/04/2007
11  01/04/1995
12  10/01/2019
```

Comment: Use `df['Startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Startdate']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: Or `df['Startdate'] = df['Startdate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')`